# C , execution at terminal gives error "Killed : 9"

Tags: c

Am doing this coursework in a very tedious way I know , but it is due tomorrow so I will just have to stick with this way for now because I dont have much time to figure out another. what this code does it it takes a 10 digit number and divides it into 10 digits, checks for every possibility from 1 to this number , if the sum of the 10 digits equals 37 , if it is , it increments a counter giving out the total number of numbers that there digits add up to 37. Problem is with such large number I guess something wrong with the memory allocation and this stuff happens, when I run it on the macOS terminal it gives me the error "Killed : 9" (after some time ofc)
Here is my source code ( In C Language):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
long long *counter = malloc(9999999999 * sizeof(*counter)); // size of array should be up to 9999999999
long long counter2 = 1; // long long because counter 2 goes up to 10 digits , MAX 9999999999
int FirstDigit, secondDigit ,ThirdDigit , fourthdigit, fifthdigit , sixthdigit,seventhdigit,eightdigit,ninthdigit,tenthdigit ;
unsigned long   z2 , z3  ,c , z1  , z4 , z5,z6 ,z7; // max 9 digits
unsigned long count = 0; // max 9 digits

for (long long i = 1 ; i<9999999999 ; i++) 
{
    counter[i] = counter2; // appends number to array
    counter2 += 1;   // increments counter for next append

    FirstDigit = counter[i] / 1000000000; 

    z1= counter[i] / 100000000;
    secondDigit = z1 % 10;

    c = counter[i] / 10000000;
    ThirdDigit = c % 10 ; // a holds 3rd digit

    z3 = counter[i] / 1000000;
    fourthdigit = z3 % 10; // d holds 2nd digit

    z2 =  counter[i] /100000; 
    fifthdigit =  z2 % 10; 

    z4 = counter[i] / 10000;
    sixthdigit = z4 % 10;  

    z5 = counter[i] / 1000;
    seventhdigit = z5 % 10;

    z6 = counter[i] / 100;
    eightdigit = z6 % 10;

    z7 = counter[i] / 10;
    ninthdigit = z7 % 10;

    tenthdigit = counter[i] % 10;  


    if( (FirstDigit + secondDigit + ThirdDigit  + fourthdigit + fifthdigit + sixthdigit + seventhdigit +eightdigit + ninthdigit + tenthdigit) == 37 )
    {
        count+= 1;
    }    

}
printf("%lu\n", count );
```

}

Comment: start by checking the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Why do you need to allocate such a big chunk of memory `malloc(9999999999 * sizeof(*counter));`?

Comment: `malloc(9999999999 * sizeof(*counter)); ` this is a red flag to me. You are demanding atleast 74 GBs of memory. Are you sure your machine has that much physical memory and your OS is ready to assign it?

Comment: `9` is the code for a `SIGSEGV` otherwise known as a segfault.  Somewhere you're writing to or reading from uninitialized memory or something like that.

Comment: Yeah - why are you storing them all?  I would stringify the number, iterate the chars, suntract '0' for each, add, check if >36 each time and break if so, check for 37 at end, inc count if equal.  No need to store them all.

Comment: This is a really good assignment, I got what you want to do. You have to ask user to input a 10-digit number and then starting from 1 to up to that 10-digit number you have to calculate the sum of the digits of every number and increment a variable to count how many times the sum of the digits is 37, i.e. how many numbers between 1 and that 10-digit number has sum of digits 37.
You need to write a very optimized code for this because a simple loop is not going to work. Please take your time a think on this assignment a bit.

Comment: @Martin James , can u elaborate more, how to  do that?

Answer (score 1):

After this

```
long long *counter = malloc(9999999999 * sizeof(*counter));
```

put

```
printf("Address returned by malloc: %p\n", (void*) counter);
```

You'll see that it returns 0, because your system can't allocate that much memory, and now when you try to write to that address you'll get a segfault.  Always check the return codes from your `malloc`s.

Comment: The behavior of what happens when `NULL` is printed with `%p` is implementation defined. I would suggest `if (counter == NULL) {printf("Allocation of counter failed\n");}`

Comment: On my system it prints 0, but this is a good point.  I just wanted to demonstrate loudly that the `malloc` was indeed failing.

Comment: Some implementations print `(null)` in case of null pointers. OP might get confused, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that reserving several Gigabytes of memory for your application is likely to fail, indicated in that `counter` will be `NULL`. You could easily check this by writing `if(counter==NULL) { printf("could not allocate memory."); return 1; }`. If you do not check this, you will access memory which you are not allowed to access, yielding undefined behaviour, very often yielding segfaults.

BTW: for just calculating the sums of the digits, you do not need to actually store all the numbers you want to check in memory. So the complete `counter`-array is not needed. Remove the `malloc` and replace `counter[i]` with `i` in your loop:

```
for (long long i = 1 ; i<9999999999 ; i++) 
{
    FirstDigit = i / 1000000000; 

    z1= i / 100000000;
    secondDigit = z1 % 10;

    ...
}
```